# select few elements of an inner array using jq

Tags: json, shell, jq

I want create a more simple json with the same original structure but with one a small sample.

As example, If I have this json:

```json
{
    "field1": [
        {
            "a": "F1A1",
            "b": "F1B1"
        },
        {
            "a": "F1A2",
            "b": "F1B2"
        },
        {
            "a": "F1A3",
            "b": "F1B3"
        },
        {
            "a": "F1A4",
            "b": "F1B4"
        }
    ],
    "field2": [
        {
            "a": "F2A1",
            "b": "F2B1"
        },
        {
            "a": "F2A2",
            "b": "F2B2"
        }
    ],
    "field3": [
        {
            "a": "F3A1",
            "b": "F3B1"
        },
        {
            "a": "F3A2",
            "b": "F3B2"
        }
    ]

}
```

I want to get the first array element from the first field. So I was expecting this:

```json
{
    "field1": [
        {
            "a": "F1A1",
            "b": "F1B1"
        }
    ],

}
```

I executed `jq "select(.field1[0])" tmp.json` but it returns the original json.

Bonus:
As bonus, how to do the same but extracting let's say `field1` and elements in the array with `a=="F1A1"` and `a=="F1A4"`, so will expect?:

```json
{
    "field1": [
        {
            "a": "F1A1",
            "b": "F1B1"
        },
        {
            "a": "F1A4",
            "b": "F1B4"
        }
    ]

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

reduce the oouter object to your field using `{field1}`, then map this field to an array containing only the `first` item:

```bash
jq '{field1} | map_values([first])'
```

```json
{
  "field1": [
    {
      "a": "F1A1",
      "b": "F1B1"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

To filter for certain items use `select`:

```bash
jq '{field1} | map_values(map(select(.a == "F1A1" or .a == "F1A4")))'
```

```json
{
  "field1": [
    {
      "a": "F1A1",
      "b": "F1B1"
    },
    {
      "a": "F1A4",
      "b": "F1B4"
    }
  ]
}
```

---

As you can see, `select` does something different. It passes on its input if the argument evaluates to `true`. Therefore its output is either all or nothing, never just a filtered part. (Of course, you can use `select` to achieve specific filtering, as shown above.)